# Google sheet - How to change cell range without deleting it

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

In a function, let's say the SUM function, I have a range **H25:H37** I want to change this range to **H23:H40** using the mouse. The only way I could find is to delete the initial value, then I can drag the mouse to select the new value. Is there a shortcut or some keyboard trick that allows me to change the range without deleting it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`H`</kbd>**. select specific range if its only in one cell and also select within formulas:

[image: 0]